# A problem on measurability of a function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> let $f$ be a real valued finction.
>   If for each $k \gt 0, \ f^{-1}((-k,k))$ is a measurable set, then $f$ is a measurable function.

Is this statement true? I think it is true but i cannot find a proof.

Comment: Try to find a counterexample.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews I am. But i couldnt. Can you give me any hint

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it’s false.

Take $C$ to be a non-measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and $f(x)=1/2$ if $x \in C$ and $f(x)=-1/2$ else.

Answer (score 2):

Under your condition, you may only claim that $$x \mapsto f(|x|)$$ is measurable, but not the original function $f$, as pointed out by @Mindlack